# How to write data line by line from the two files into a common file in java

Tags: java, filewriter, separator

I am facing while merging two files in one (with common content)

```
public class myFileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<String> firstFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> secondFileList = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> missingRecordsInFile2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner firstFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("C://write1.txt")));
        Scanner secondFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("C://write2.txt")));

        FileWriter fWriteOne = new FileWriter(new File("C://read1.txt"));


        while (firstFile.hasNext()) {
            firstFileList.add(firstFile.next());
        }

        while (secondFile.hasNext()) {
            secondFileList.add(secondFile.next());
        }

        try {
            for (String fileOne : firstFileList) {
                boolean value = secondFileList.contains(fileOne);
                if (value) {
                    missingRecordsInFile2.add(fileOne);
                    fWriteOne.write(fileOne);
                    fWriteOne.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                }
            }
        } finally {
            fWriteOne.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**For example:**

FILE 1:

```
Yellow wall 
Red Wall 
Green wall
Black wall
```

FILE 2:

```
 Red Wall
 Black wall
 Brown wall
```

RESULTING FILE (My wish):

```
  Red Wall
  Black wall
```

But this code write file like:

CURRENT RESULTING FILE:

```
 Red
 wall
 Black
 wall
```

Comment: So, you want to get the lines those are common in both files?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will be glad for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to solution but making simple mistake. i.e. you are reading by `firstFile.next()` which gives you word by word instead of line by line, As you are interested in line by line So use `nextLine()` Like:

```
while (firstFile.hasNext()) {
    firstFileList.add(firstFile.nextLine().trim());
}

while (secondFile.hasNext()) {
    secondFileList.add(secondFile.nextLine().trim());
}

try {
    for (String fileOne : firstFileList) {
        boolean value = secondFileList.contains(fileOne);
        if (value) {
            missingRecordsInFile2.add(fileOne);
            fWriteOne.write(fileOne);
            fWriteOne.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
} finally {
    fWriteOne.close();
}
```

**MORE**

I recommend to use `String.Trim()` to avoid all extra spaces after your text, As `Red Wall_` is not equal to `Red Wall` because of a single space.

Comment: Pleasure is mine @КириллКраснобаев

Answer (score 1):

You are using the default Scanner delimiter, which is the whitespace.
You should set the delimiter to newline (either '\r' and/or '\n'), like this

```
Scanner firstFile =  new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("C://write1.txt")));
Scanner secondFile =  new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("C://write2.txt")));
firstFile.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n]+"));
secondFile.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n]+"));
```

Maybe you can also use the simpler

```
myScanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
```

but if you have multiple newlines at the end of a line, you'll end up with empty lines in the output file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store content of two files in two `List` as you did:

```
List<String> firstFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> secondFileList = new ArrayList<String>();

/***** Start : This is dummy data ********/
firstFileList.add("Yellow wall");
firstFileList.add("Red Wall");
firstFileList.add("Green wall");
firstFileList.add("Black wall");

secondFileList.add("Red Wall");
secondFileList.add("Black wall");
secondFileList.add("Brown wall");
/***** End: This is dummy data ********/

firstFileList.retainAll(secondFileList);
```

Now `firstFileList` contains all the data you need.

Comment: your answer is precise but loop is mandatory in this case as he want it to write in a file.

Comment: Yes of course. But I guess as the main problem area was to identify the common rows in both files (as mentioned in the comment section), I tried to focus on that area only. Thanks for your input.